# How do I properly use Python's C API and exceptions?

Tags: python, python-c-api

If I do something like:

```
 >>> x = int(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I immediately get a fatal error (one that would end program execution if it was in a pre-written script)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)
```

and `x` remains undefined:

```
 >>> x
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

How would I go about implementing that in Python's C API? I found some [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html) for it, but I am not sure that I know how to use it correctly.

Here is what I have been trying:

1. Print:

   ```
    if(something) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Oh no!");
        PyErr_Print();
    }
   ```

   This, unfortunately, only prints the exception and the program continues. Additionally,—if I understand it correctly—`PyErr_Print()` removes the exception from some sort of queue so Python thinks that it is handled. This is what it looks like:

   ```
    >>> import awesomemod
    >>> x = awesomemod.thing()
    TypeError: Oh no!
    >>> x # x is defined because the function returns None eventually
    >>>
   ```
2. `PyErr_Occurred()`:

   ```
    if(something) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Oh no!");
        PyErr_Occurred();
    }
   ```

   Behavior:

   ```
    >>> import awesomemod
    >>> awesomemod.thing()
    >>>
    TypeError: Oh no!
    >>>
   ```

   So it does it kind of late...
3. `return PyErr_Occurred()`:

   ```
    if(something) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Oh no!");
        return PyErr_Occurred();
    }
   ```

   Behavior:

   ```
    >>> import awesomemod
    >>> awesomemod.thing()
    <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
    >>>
    TypeError: Oh no!
   ```

   This one is just really weird.

What do I need to do to get the behavior of built-in functions?

**Edit:** I tried what @user2864740 suggested in a comment and it worked perfectly!

```
 if(something) {
     PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Oh no!");
     return (PyObject *) NULL;
 }
```

Comment: IIRC, just `PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Oh no!")` should be sufficient - make sure to *skip* all the other code in the C method as well.

Comment: You must return NULL too.

Comment: Also, it is okay to set an exception multiple times in the same call stack. Only the last exception will still be set and thrown when you return to Python.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Raising an exception in C is done by setting the exception object or string and then returning `NULL` from the function.

Answer (score 5):

As [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233091):

> Raising an exception in C is done by setting the exception object or string and then returning NULL from the function.

There are convenience functions which make this easy to do for common exception types. For example, [`PyErr_NoMemory`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_NoMemory) can be used like this:

```c
PyObject *my_function(void)
{
    return PyErr_NoMemory();  // Sets the exception and returns NULL
}
```

Comment: Under https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html, you can find the documentation for the current Python 3.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt, I'm not sure why I cited the Python 2 docs (even in 2019). Fortunately, the referenced API is exactly the same in Python 3, so I simply updated the URL to point to the Python 3 version.